# Is there a way with htaccess to redirect a URL if URL contains foo or bar?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Is there a way with htaccess to always redirect a URL to the home page if URL contains foo or bar?

I think I just need to be a bit more clear on what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to do this with a Wordpress website. I have tried a few different redirects, but none seem to be working.

What I am trying to do is if a URL such as:
http://www.domain.com/folder/RandomPartOfURL-xxx/
or
http://www.domain.com/folder/RandomPartOfURL-yyy/

The system redirects the user back to another page. The xxx or yyy on the end of the URL will always be the same 2 or 3 things, but the random part is always random. The URL's that I need to redirect will always be in this format and all of the URL's that meet this structure just need to get directed to the same exact "catch all" URL.

I just dont have enough of a grasp on htaccess to get this to work the way I want yet. I can get it to work where all URL's accessed within the folder redirect, but most of the URL's within that folder structure still need to work correctly.

Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I got this figured out. Basically what I needed is below in case anyone else needs it:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*-xxx|.*-yyy) PageURL.html [R=301,NC,L]
```